# XSLT 2.0 How to select elements by local-name() = $variable and value of local-name in $variable2

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Lets say you have a `call-template` statement like so:

```
<!-- group_by represents local-name to group off of -->
<xsl:variable name="group_by" select="'ACCOUNT_3'"/>
. . . 
<!-- call template to build special columns -->
<xsl:call-template name="special-cols">
  <xsl:with-param name="cat" as="element()" select="current-group()"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="annual_budget" as="element()" select="$annual_budget/*[(local-name()=$group_by)=current-grouping-key()]"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="sign" as="xs:integer" select="$sign"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="year" as="xs:integer" select="$year"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

My issue lies in this line:

`<xsl:with-param name="annual_budget" as="element()" select="$annual_budget/*[(local-name()=$group_by)=current-grouping-key()]"/>`

I'm wanting to compare the value of as element with the `current-grouping-key()`, but the element to compare could be different based how the report is generated. `$group_by` holds the string representation of the `local-name()` of the value to compare. Is there a way to grab the element's underlying value for comparison using `$group_by`?

Comment: If the expression `$annual_budget/*[local-name()=$group_by]` selects elements you are interested in and you also want to compare the value of the element then add another predicate e.g. `$annual_budget/*[local-name()=$group_by][. = expression-or-value-to-compare-to]` or use an `and` e.g. `$annual_budget/*[local-name()=$group_by and . = expression-or-value-to-compare-to]`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Interesting, so the `.` can be used to reference the underlying value of the element I selected using `[local-name()=$group_by]`? If that is the case, nice!

I did find a sort of okay solution using `if/then/else` statements but this is much cleaner and scalable so I'll try to implement this. Thank you.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-context-item-expression and/or https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-context-item-expression and/or https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev "`.` selects the context node"